# What is the preprocessor define for C++ language in Xcode precompile header?

Tags: c++, xcode, pch

In my `Prefix.pch` file I am using `__OBJC__` preprocessor define for compilation of Objective C headers.  What is the equivalent for compilation of C++ headers?

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#endif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a standard preprocessor constant, `__cplusplus`. Its value is expanded to version number of C++ standard being used:

> **__cplusplus**
>
> denotes the version of C++ standard that is being used, expands to
>   value 199711L (until C++11), 201103L (C++11), 201402L (C++14), or
>   201703L (C++17)

Source: [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace)

So, you can write, for example:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
  #if __cplusplus >= 201103L
    // include new stuff
  #else
    // use legacy features
  #endif
#endif
```